# Obstacles in sensor deadzone

Tags: navigation, ros2, kinect, ros-melodic, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the last step for in my setup is navigation. I got everything working so far. The last question remaining for me is: Is it currently possible to specify a dead zone for my sensor when using pointcloud data. The only thread i could find, is from [2015](https://answers.ros.org/question/219513/how-to-prevent-costmap-to-clear-obstacles-that-are-too-close-for-the-kinect-to-detect/). The problem is that obstacles are cleared when the camera is losing them if they are entering the deadzone. So the global planner is adjusting the route and drives into the obstacle infront of it.

I'm using a kinect v1 camera which has a dead zone of something around 0,6m. I want to avoid using laserscan because i want to have 3D data for my voxel layer. I know that the laserscan msg has a range_min value. Is there something similar for processing pointcloud data ? Or is it possible to hack the code of costmap2d to realise such behavior ?

Thank you :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355150/obstacles-in-sensor-deadzone/) by [Chris91](https://answers.ros.org/users/54232/chris91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a minimum obstacle range parameter in Spatio-Temporal Voxel Layer (https://github.com/SteveMacenski/spatio_temporal_voxel_layer) called `min_z`. This is however not currently supported in the standard Voxel Layer.

From my experience, I'm not exactly sure why it's not already supported so I filed a ticket in ROS2 navigation stack to implement https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/1809. I think that's a worthy addition and wouldn't take someone too long to implement (hint hint, nudge nudge).

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chris91](https://answers.ros.org/users/54232/chris91/) on 2020-06-19**:
Interesting i will take a look @ it. I will give you feedback :)

**Comment by [Chris91](https://answers.ros.org/users/54232/chris91/) on 2020-06-21**:
It's working like a charm. Great work you did there. I have one question you might be able to easly answer. The voxel_decay value, does it influence clearings inside the min_z area ?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-01-07**:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/2126 the capability for Voxel Layer to deal with min Z will also be available soon, certainly by Galactic.